# Crystal Report Goes Blank on moving from one PC to Another

Tags: c#, mysql, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I designed a report in crystal report v13. Steps that i followed are,

1. create a system dsn for Mysql with database details in
   administration tools.
2. go to crystal report, click on database->database expert->create new
   connection -> odbc -> new connection and selected the dsn I created.
3. When the connection is added i clicked on add command and added my report command.
4. Then Designed the report.
5. loaded and printed report using C#

once I designed the report tested with printing , I moved my report file(.rpt file) to another PC.Printing through C# in this system Failed(Blank Report).Then I opened up the report in crystal report in this system and previewed.The Report was Blank.

So I Followed first two steps Which I did in My PC(above mention step 1 and 2).
Then again I preview it. The Report Was Blank With no details from database but other skeletal structure was present(I mean except values from database).

What did i Do Wrong Here?

I had to do step 3 and step 4 again in this PC. Designing the report in every system I transfer the report file is pathetic. Can Anyone Tell Me what step i am missing here?

Comment: Create the same DSN as you create in first system and try to run..... You don't need to design on every system

Comment: @siva, I tried this already . i created same dsn as in first system and i opened the report in crystal report and refreshed. gave parameters. but still it goes blank

Comment: Take the query and fire it on database and check whether you are getting any result or not....if that is also fine then check whether you are using correct database or not....meanwhile which database are you using?